# Change viewport in Google Maps API to Fusion Table Polygon Layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, viewport, google-fusion-tables

I've developed a javascript web application that will show single polygon layers (though some are multi-part) from a Google Fusion Table on the Google Maps API canvas, but the polygons vary in size and location.  When I load each of them, I'd like to set the viewport of the map so that the user can actually find the polygon.

My first thought was to use  `google.maps.Maps.fitBounds()` but for that, it seems like I need to somehow convert my geometry into a `LatLngBounds` which I'm not sure how to do.  I've seen the examples for point features, but not polygons.   Is there a quick script to parse the KML geometry into points which I can then use to create the LatLngBounds either on the fly or as a new table attribute?

I'd be open to other ways to reset the viewport as well - this is just the avenue that I envision right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the FusionTable for the Polygon data either using GViz ([example using GViz and geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/www_advocacy_ucla_edu_Assembly_MapC.html)) or the [Fusion Tables API v1](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started), add all the coordinates to a google.maps.LatLngBounds, using [google.maps.LatLngBounds.extend](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) then call [google.maps.Map.fitBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) on the resulting bounds.

Comment: Thanks, these examples are exactly what I needed.